# Get NpgSql Entity Framework query text

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.2.0.
I want to be able to see the query that will be executed on the database.
Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: do you have any logger already configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally there is no need to configure `LoggerFactory` explcitly if you are using `.AddDbContext` or `.AddDbContextPool` on service registration. EF Core automatically grabs existing logger factory (configured) and uses Debug level log in order to log queries.

You can alternatively enable

```
builder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();  // << Enables query parameter/value logging
builder.EnableDetailedErrors(); // << Enables Detailed Errors such as parameter mapping errors
builder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => 
    warnings.Log(CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning));  << Includes ignored warnings
```

The only thing you need to do is to change the logging level accordingly

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    ....
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information"
  }
}
```

or you may use Custom logger factory

```
public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
    = new LoggerFactory(new[]
    {
        new ConsoleLoggerProvider((category, level)
            => category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name
               && level == LogLevel.Information, true)
    });
```